# Unit testing razor views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, razor

"The Razor parser and view engine can be instantiated and used outside of the ASP.NET application domain.  This means you can directly instantiate and use it within a unit test project without any dependencies on running ASP.NET"

Any ideas how can I do it ??

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436994/how-to-unit-test-a-razor-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was to create a unit test project and then added the mvc project into the reference. Then I instantited the controller object and invoke its action method.

You should be able to do assertion to check the contents of the view.

I think the easiest way to do is to create a new dummy mvc 3 project with a unit test project come with it. It will create an example Test Method for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanx for the reply.This [blog post](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/unit-test-your-mvc-views-using-razor.html) also helped me a lot. If you wish you can also look into this. Thanx again

Comment: Did that not test the Controller rather than the view? How did you get the rendered HTML (as a string)???

Comment: Note that the solution I proposed was almost decade ago, so it might be outdated by now. The gist is that you can invoke the controller action that returns a razorview/contentview and extract the HTML content from there.