# How to unit-test a razor-view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, razor

When Scott Guthrie [first blogged on Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-razor), he wrote

> The new view engine implementation will support the ability to unit test views (without requiring a controller or web-server, and can be hosted in any unit test project – no special app-domain required).

However, I can find no other statement (or example) regarding razor-testability.
There are pointers to using the [`CodelanguageServie`](http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2010/7/22/using-the-razor-parser-outside-of-aspnet.html) or [RazorGenerator](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/unit-test-your-mvc-views-using-razor.html) or [some self-made renderer](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/28/mvc-3-razor-view-engine-without-a-controller/) - non of which I would call "by design".

Is it currently possible to unit test a razor view the simple way? (In an asp.net mvc-application, that is. I.e. NancyFx brings testability in it's nancy.testing-package.)

(And currently I don't care [if views should be tested or not](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/why-is-testing-mvc-views-frowned-upon).)

I know there are [loads of questions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/razor+unit-testing), but most of them are rather old...

Answer (score 1):

What I think you can unit test any  Razor view like following:

```
ViewResult v = View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.ViewName))
                v.ViewName = RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
            ViewEngineResult result = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter textwriter = new StringWriter(sb);
            HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(textwriter);
            if (v.View == null)
            {
                result = new ViewEngineResult(new RazorView(ControllerContext,"~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", null,false,null), new RazorViewEngine());
                v.View = result.View;
            }
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, v.View, ViewData, TempData, htmlwriter);
            v.View.Render(viewContext, htmlwriter);
            string html = sb.ToString();
```

After this,you can parse the html to check the content with the specification.

Comment: This suggestion still requires a controller including controller context with various properties provided. While they can be mocked to some degree, this code - outside of a controller running with a valid HttpContext.Current - runs into an NRE (NullReferenceException) in `System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean& keyFromVPP)`. So the search for an easy way to test a view e.g. implementation of something like `RazorView.Render(string viewName, object model)`, continues. Views/partials still don't seem to be testable.